# Preserving relations and operations in an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, automorphism-group

An automorphism is an isomorphism of an algebraic structure with itself.

Let's review an isomorphism $i$ of two linearly ordered groups $G(+,<)$ and $F(*,<)$.

$i$ is linear *order-preserving* when $a < b \iff i(a) < i(b)$ for any elements $a$ and $b$ in $G$.

Let's note that every linear order induces the reverse order: $G(+, <, >)$, $F(*, <, >)$.

An isomorphism $i^*$ is linear *order-reversing* when $a < b \iff i(a) > i(b) \iff i(b) < i(a)$.

Any linear *order-preserving* isomorphism $i$ induces linear *order-reversing* isomorphism $i^*$.

In case $G$ and $F$ are different, choosing between $<$ and $>$ in each of the groups is an arbitrary decision, so one can say $i$ and $i^*$ are equivalent.

It looks like this is not the case when we talk about automorphisms.

Let's assume $G$ is commutative and review the inversion automorphism $i(a) = -a$.

$i$ is *order-reversing* since $a < b \iff -b < -a$.

But in this case we can clearly see the difference between *order-preserving* and *order-reversing* automorphisms: $i$ maps $<$ to $>$ on the same set.

I am wondering if it make sense to explicitly say if an automorphism keeps operations and relations the same?

I've never thought of mapping $+$ to $\times$ in an automorphism of an algebraic structure $(+, \times)$.

Are there practical examples of such mapping?

There was a similar discussion with no positive conclusion in here:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Difference_between_an_order_automorphism_and_order_isomoprhism

Comment: I don't do order theory, but I think that an "order-reversing" isomorphism $(G,<_G)\to (H,<_H)$ is better thought of as an isomorphism to the group $(H,>_H)$, or perhaps  as an isomorphism from the domain $(G,>_G)$, much in the same way as we view a contravariant functor $F:C\to D$ as being actually a functor from $C^{\text{op}}$ to $D$. In this light, order reversing isomorphisms between two are not isomorphisms between the the initial objects but isomorphisms between different objects. Thus automorphisms of $(G,<_G)$ should be order-preserving under this viewpoint.

Comment: Please don't use `$...$` for words in italics, such as `$order-preserving$`. The correct markup is `*order-preserving*`. Using `$` for math symbols such as `$i$` is good, of course.

Comment: @egreg: Got it. Thank you.